# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Not sure why

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactive-programming

```js
const list = props.things.toDo.map(
  function(thing) {
    return(
      <li>{thing.name}</li>
    );
  }
);
```

Cant figure this out keep getting this react warning?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const list = props.things.toDo.map((x, i) => <li key={i}>{thing.name}</li>);
```

Your code can be condensed down to the above code instead. As other has mentioned, whenever we rendering a list, React will need each and every individual element to be unique which in that case it needs a `key` prop, but instead of using `key={thing.name}` which I believe there is a chance that `thing.name` is not unique, I would normally use index instead which is 100% guaranteed to be unique

Answer (score 2):

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li key={number.toString()}>
    {number}
  </li>
);
```

---

The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys:

```js
const list = props.things.toDo.map(
  function(thing) {
    return(
      <li key={thing.id}>{thing.name}</li>
    );
  }
);
```

---

When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort:

```js
const list = props.things.toDo.map(
  function(thing, index) {
    return(
      <li key={index}>{thing.name}</li>
    );
  }
);
```

We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.  If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then React will default to using indexes as keys.

---

**Reference**: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, try this:

```
<li key={thing.name}>{thing.name}</li>
```

Then read up on the React docs for [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

You'll probably want to replace the key with a truly unique value, if `thing.name` is not guaranteed to be the same across items.